# HTTP POST from c#, php saves POST as image

Tags: c#, php, post, httpwebrequest

In c# i convert an image to base64 string and then post it to a php script which saves it as a image file in the server.

the php:

```
<?php 
file_put_contents($_POST["name"], base64_decode($_POST["file"])); 
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="file" />

<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string param = "name=image.jpg&file=" + ImageToBase64(p.Image);

           post(param, "urlToPHPfileShown");
        }
        public string ImageToBase64(Image image)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Convert Image to byte[]
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

                // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
                string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                return base64String;
            }
        }
        public string post(string param, string url)
        {

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            string postArgs = param;

            req.Method = "POST";
            req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            req.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postArgs);
            req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            using (Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                reqStream.Close();
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(respStream))
                {
                    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    return s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does create the file on the server, however the file does not work. 
if i submit the form data using Google chrome with the data generated from the ImageToBase64 method the file does indeed work.

Comment: Since you are using POST, why not just POST the whole image as a byte array instead of a string? Strings would be more suitable for a GET request.

Comment: How would i do that? I thought a post needed to be a string?

Comment: Well first, you need to understand the difference between POST and GET. You can look up how to post data here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the file does not work."  ?  I suggest performing a binary comparison between the original file and the saved file to detect any problems, e.g. if the data are being truncated vs. the file is simply garbage.